# How to get Parameter from a post request in java?

Tags: java, getparameter

I am trying to upload a simple image to server. Other than image data I have 1 more parameter which specifies to whom it belongs.

Client:

```
<form method="POST" action="../servlet" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="imgdata">
    <input type="text" class="se" style="display:none;" name="se"/>
    <div class="browser">
        <label class="take">
        <input type="file" name="ImagesFile" class="Propicselecter_file" id="Propicselecter_file" size="1" accept="image/*" id="imagetoupload" name="fname1"/>
        <span>Browse</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="sub" value="Finish"/>
</form>
```

Then in server I have:

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
String name = request.getParameter("se");
System.out.println(name);

MultipartRequest multipartRequest = new MultipartRequest(request, "C:/", 5000000, "ISO-8859-1", new DefaultFileRenamePolicy());
```

The image being sent is perfectly saved at `c:/name.extension`, but the problem is that I am getting name parameter as `null`.

Full Stack exception:

```
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2733)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2699)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1096)
at duck.reg.pack.stkbkimgup.doPost(stkbkimgup.java:28)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:1110)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20394292/how-to-pass-parameter-in-multipart-post-request

Comment: @javaguy I just tried `for( Part p : request.getParts() ) {
      if( "se".equals(p.getName()) ) {
       System.out.println(p.getName());
      } else {
       System.out.println(p.getName());
      }
  }`      Now I am getting an exception saying: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to process parts as no multi-part configuration has been provided`

Comment: Can you add your modified code fully  and full stack trace ?

Comment: Did you set allowCasualMultipartParsing="true" in your context.xml, see details in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24578680/error-unable-to-process-parts-as-no-multi-part-configuration-has-been-provided

Comment: @javaguy I updated my question you read the full exception in my question above

Comment: Did you try adding allowCasualMultipartParsing="true" in your context.xml ?